# Why my Odoo 11 installation never finish?

Tags: odoo-11

I'm trying to install Odoo v11 on Ubuntu 16.04 through the following command:

sudo apt-get install odoo

The installation starts but it stays waiting when its arrive to "Setting up odoo (11.0.20181115)" step. Never finish.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to install odoo from source. I may provide you a procedure, just follow the [link](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/install-an-odoo-11-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/) and your odoo will be installed from source. I have installed serveral times in Ubuntu and CentOS, both operating system. And there were no issues.