# Odoo 10 installation never finish (Setting up odoo)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, failed-installation

I have odoo installed on my server that I want to update.
The problem is the upgrade procedure never end. The only message is :
Setting up odoo (10.0.20181203) ...
Even after several hours nothing has changed.
I've tried to remove the package and reinstall it but the same thing happens.

The problem is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53326489/why-my-odoo-11-installation-never-finish) (but not with the same version). But for ease of use and maintainability I really prefer use the apt option instead of having install from the sources.

Coud you help me to :

- Best option : solve the odoo problem
- At least : which log to look to check where the problem is. I've looked on term.log (apt) but it only show the current step and not what the system is doing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# Script for installing Odoo V10 on Ubuntu 16.04, 15.04, 14.04 (could be used for other version too)
################################################################################

##fixed parameters
#odoo
OE_USER="odoo"
OE_HOME="/opt/odoo/$OE_USER"
OE_HOME_EXT="/opt/odoo/$OE_USER/${OE_USER}-server"
#The default port where this Odoo instance will run under (provided you use the command -c in the terminal)
#Set to true if you want to install it, false if you don't need it or have it already installed.
INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF="True"
#Set the default Odoo port (you still have to use -c /etc/odoo-server.conf for example to use this.)
OE_PORT="8069"
#Choose the Odoo version which you want to install. For example: 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0 or saas-6. When using 'trunk' the master version will be installed.
#IMPORTANT! This script contains extra libraries that are specifically needed for Odoo 10.0
OE_VERSION="10.0"
# Set this to True if you want to install Odoo 10 Enterprise!
IS_ENTERPRISE="False"
#set the superadmin password
OE_SUPERADMIN="admin"
OE_CONFIG="${OE_USER}-server"

##
###  WKHTMLTOPDF download links
## === Ubuntu Trusty x64 & x32 === (for other distributions please replace these two links,
## in order to have correct version of wkhtmltox installed, for a danger note refer to 
## https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html#deb ):
WKHTMLTOX_X64=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
WKHTMLTOX_X32=https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
#--------------------------------------------------
# Update Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Update Server ----"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install PostgreSQL Server
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install PostgreSQL Server ----"
sudo apt-get install postgresql -y

echo -e "\n---- Creating the ODOO PostgreSQL User  ----"
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s $OE_USER" 2> /dev/null || true

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Dependencies
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n---- Install tool packages ----"
sudo apt-get install wget git python-pip gdebi-core -y

echo -e "\n---- Install python packages ----"
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-feedparser python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-openid python-psycopg2 python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi python-docutils python-psutil python-mock python-unittest2 python-jinja2 python-pypdf python-decorator python-requests python-passlib python-pil -y python-suds

echo -e "\n---- Install python libraries ----"
sudo pip install gdata psycogreen ofxparse XlsxWriter xlrd

echo -e "\n--- Install other required packages"
sudo apt-get install node-clean-css -y
sudo apt-get install node-less -y
sudo apt-get install python-gevent -y

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install Wkhtmltopdf if needed
#--------------------------------------------------
if [ $INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF = "True" ]; then
  echo -e "\n---- Install wkhtml and place shortcuts on correct place for ODOO 10 ----"
  #pick up correct one from x64 & x32 versions:
  if [ "`getconf LONG_BIT`" == "64" ];then
      _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X64
  else
      _url=$WKHTMLTOX_X32
  fi
  sudo wget $_url
  sudo gdebi --n `basename $_url`
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
else
  echo "Wkhtmltopdf isn't installed due to the choice of the user!"
fi

echo -e "\n---- Create ODOO system user ----"
sudo adduser --system --quiet --shell=/bin/bash --home=$OE_HOME --gecos 'ODOO' --group $OE_USER
#The user should also be added to the sudo'ers group.
sudo adduser $OE_USER sudo

echo -e "\n---- Create Log directory ----"
sudo mkdir /var/log/$OE_USER
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /var/log/$OE_USER

#--------------------------------------------------
# Install ODOO
#--------------------------------------------------
echo -e "\n==== Installing ODOO Server ===="
sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch $OE_VERSION https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo $OE_HOME_EXT/

if [ $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
    # Odoo Enterprise install!
    echo -e "\n--- Create symlink for node"
    sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise"
    sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons"

    GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.0 https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
    while [[ $GITHUB_RESPONSE == *"Authentication"* ]]; do
        echo "------------------------WARNING------------------------------"
        echo "Your authentication with Github has failed! Please try again."
        printf "In order to clone and install the Odoo enterprise version you \nneed to be an offical Odoo partner and you need access to\nhttp://github.com/odoo/enterprise.\n"
        echo "TIP: Press ctrl+c to stop this script."
        echo "-------------------------------------------------------------"
        echo " "
        GITHUB_RESPONSE=$(sudo git clone --depth 1 --branch 10.0 https://www.github.com/odoo/enterprise "$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons" 2>&1)
    done

    echo -e "\n---- Added Enterprise code under $OE_HOME/enterprise/addons ----"
    echo -e "\n---- Installing Enterprise specific libraries ----"
    sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
    sudo npm install -g less
    sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
fi

echo -e "\n---- Create custom module directory ----"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom"
sudo su $OE_USER -c "mkdir $OE_HOME/custom/addons"

echo -e "\n---- Setting permissions on home folder ----"
sudo chown -R $OE_USER:$OE_USER $OE_HOME/*

echo -e "* Create server config file"
sudo cp $OE_HOME_EXT/debian/odoo.conf /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chown $OE_USER:$OE_USER /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo chmod 640 /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf

echo -e "* Change server config file"
sudo sed -i s/"db_user = .*"/"db_user = $OE_USER"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo sed -i s/"; admin_passwd.*"/"admin_passwd = $OE_SUPERADMIN"/g /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf
sudo su root -c "echo '[options]' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
sudo su root -c "echo 'logfile = /var/log/$OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG$1.log' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
if [  $IS_ENTERPRISE = "True" ]; then
    sudo su root -c "echo 'addons_path=$OE_HOME/enterprise/addons,$OE_HOME_EXT/addons' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
else
    sudo su root -c "echo 'addons_path=$OE_HOME_EXT/addons,$OE_HOME/custom/addons' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"
fi

echo -e "* Create startup file"
sudo su root -c "echo '#!/bin/sh' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo su root -c "echo 'sudo -u $OE_USER $OE_HOME_EXT/openerp-server --config=/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf' >> $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh"
sudo chmod 755 $OE_HOME_EXT/start.sh

#--------------------------------------------------
# Adding ODOO as a deamon (initscript)
#--------------------------------------------------

echo -e "* Create init file"
cat <<EOF > ~/$OE_CONFIG
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: $OE_CONFIG
# Required-Start: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Required-Stop: \$remote_fs \$syslog
# Should-Start: \$network
# Should-Stop: \$network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Enterprise Business Applications
# Description: ODOO Business Applications
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=$OE_HOME_EXT/odoo-bin
NAME=$OE_CONFIG
DESC=$OE_CONFIG

# Specify the user name (Default: odoo).
USER=$OE_USER

# Specify an alternate config file (Default: /etc/openerp-server.conf).
CONFIGFILE="/etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"

# pidfile
PIDFILE=/var/run/\${NAME}.pid

# Additional options that are passed to the Daemon.
DAEMON_OPTS="-c \$CONFIGFILE"
[ -x \$DAEMON ] || exit 0
[ -f \$CONFIGFILE ] || exit 0
checkpid() {
[ -f \$PIDFILE ] || return 1
pid=\`cat \$PIDFILE\`
[ -d /proc/\$pid ] && return 0
return 1
}

case "\${1}" in
start)
echo -n "Starting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
stop)
echo -n "Stopping \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
echo "\${NAME}."
;;

restart|force-reload)
echo -n "Restarting \${DESC}: "
start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--oknodo
sleep 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile \$PIDFILE \
--chuid \$USER --background --make-pidfile \
--exec \$DAEMON -- \$DAEMON_OPTS
echo "\${NAME}."
;;
*)
N=/etc/init.d/\$NAME
echo "Usage: \$NAME {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
exit 1
;;

esac
exit 0
EOF

echo -e "* Security Init File"
sudo mv ~/$OE_CONFIG /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG
sudo chown root: /etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG

echo -e "* Change default xmlrpc port"
sudo su root -c "echo 'xmlrpc_port = $OE_PORT' >> /etc/${OE_CONFIG}.conf"

echo -e "* Start ODOO on Startup"
sudo update-rc.d $OE_CONFIG defaults

echo -e "* Starting Odoo Service"
sudo su root -c "/etc/init.d/$OE_CONFIG start"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Done! The Odoo server is up and running. Specifications:"
echo "Port: $OE_PORT"
echo "User service: $OE_USER"
echo "User PostgreSQL: $OE_USER"
echo "Code location: $OE_USER"
echo "Addons folder: $OE_USER/$OE_CONFIG/addons/"
echo "Start Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG start"
echo "Stop Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG stop"
echo "Restart Odoo service: sudo service $OE_CONFIG restart"
echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
```

Save the above in a file and save with an extension of '.sh'. Then open the terminal from where you saved the file. Then type sudo bash .sh

Hope this will work. Don't forget to put tick mark if this works. Also give me an upvote too.

Comment: Hi Pablo Escobar,

Thanks for your help. This was not what I was looking for as I really want to keep the apt process instead of downloading and compiling the sources.
But your script helped me as I've downloaded all the dependencies and after that the update process has worked...

Thanks 

A.

Comment: Okie .. Don't forget to put the tick mark ! Happy coding bro !